# Quarkus - Keycloak Performance Issue

Tags: java, keycloak, quarkus

I’m using quarkus (java) to expose my rest api integrated wirh keycloak for the authentication.

I’m using quarkus oidc and keycloak auth for the lib (1.10.5.final)

During performance test, my server is CPU 3 core and RAM 2 Gb, I’ve found performance issue there.

For comparation,
Disable the auth to keycloak, I can get around 500tps
Enable the auth, I only get 80 tps

I saw the slownes is bcs my token need to be validated to keycloak server and raise the CPU usage.

May I know how to tune the performance?

Thanks

Comment: The advantage of oidc tokens is that you don't need server (keycloak) to validate token. You need to contact server just once to download public key and then it can be used fot offline validation. I don't think you need tunning, but better implementation of service provider on your side.

Comment: Hi Jan Garaj, I;m just following the guidance from this documentation : https://quarkus.io/guides/security-openid-connect <br/> I change log level to debug and found that the process is like that. Do you gave github code sample to implement this quarkus and keycloak integration with better  implementation? Thks